# How to create a specific modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this little problem when trying to create the modal box animation. I have managed to make the background fade to black and the modal box slides in, but when i clicked the close button only the modal box will slide up and not the background returning to normal and let me click on anything else on the page
Please help, thanks in advance.

```
.modal{
display:none;
z-index:99;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.modal-content{
position:relative;
width:90%;
height:90%;
margin: 2% auto;
background-color: #dfdde0;
display:none;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-name:slide-down-modal;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.modal-content img{
float:right;
height:24px;
width:24px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:10px;
opacity:0.5;
}

.modal-content img:hover{
opacity:1;
}

@keyframes slide-down-modal{
from{top:-700px}
to{top:0}
}

@keyframes slide-up-modal{
from{top:0; opacity:1}
to{top:-700px; opacity:0}
}
```

here is the javascript part

```
function openModal(){
var modal=document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
var modalContent=document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
modal.style.display="block";
modalContent.style.display="block";
}

function closeModal(){
var modal=document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
var modalContent=document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
modalContent.style.animationName="slide-up-modal";
if($(".modal").css("display")=="block"){
    $(".modal").css("display", "none");
};
}
```

and the html

```
<div onclick="openModal()">click me</div>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <img onclick="closeModal()" src="X.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

somehow i managed to close both but simultaneously though :(

Comment: Please share your code with us that you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED

```js
$(".openModal").click(function(){
 $(".modal").fadeIn("slow", function(){
   $(this).find(".modal-content").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
$(".closeModal").click(function(){
 $(".modal-content").fadeOut("slow", function(){
   $(this).parent(".modal").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.modal{
display:none;
z-index:99;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.modal-content{
position:relative;
width:90%;
height:90%;
margin: 2% auto;
display:none;
background-color: #dfdde0;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-name:slide-down-modal;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.modal-content img{
float:right;
height:24px;
width:24px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:10px;
opacity:0.5;
}

.modal-content img:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openModal">click me</div>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <img class="closeModal" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1008/quiet/128/no.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks but it still close both at the same ime but not one after the other :D

Comment: Updated gain. Now is closing first content then background

Comment: you are a life saver! Again forgive me as i am getting used to html/css/js ;_;